# How can I make a custom delegate for my ListView?

Tags: qml

I'm trying to make a custom ListView (AppDataListView) that can be used for data manipulation (essentially having a bunch of inputs). The problem I'm having is finding a way to tell AppDataListView what input types to use in the delegate of the ListView.

I currently try and do this by creating a loader in the ListView delegate, setting its source to a property of type Component, and then when I create an instance of AppDataListView, I specify the Component... However, I don't have any access to the model data, so it's kind of pointless.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick .Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: sampleData
        ListElement {
            itemId: 1
            name: "Name1"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemId: 2
            name: "Name2"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemId: 3
            name: "Name3"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemId: 4
            name: "Name4"
        }
    }

    AppDataListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        headers: ["ID", "Name"]
        model: sampleData
        delegate: Component {
            RowLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent
                TextArea {
                    // I can't access itemId from here even though this is loaded into the delegate.
                    text: itemId
                }
                TextArea {
                    // I can't access name from here even though this is loaded into the delegate.
                    text: name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AppDataListView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Rectangle {
    property var headers: []
    property alias model: listView.model
    property alias listView: listView
    required property Component delegate;

    id: root
    color: "#bdbdbd"

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 1
        spacing:0

        RowLayout {
            spacing: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop

            Item {
                Layout.minimumWidth: 30
                Layout.maximumWidth: 30
            }

            Repeater {
                id: headerRepeater
                model: headers
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#FFFFFF" }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "#F1F1F1" }
                        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#FFFFFF" }
                    }

                    Label {
                        text: modelData
                        padding: 5
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        ListView {
            id: listView
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            interactive: true
            clip: true
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
            spacing: 1
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                active: true
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            }

            delegate:  RowLayout {
                width: parent.width
                spacing: 1

                Button {
                    id: rowBtn
                    Layout.minimumWidth: 30
                    Layout.maximumWidth: 30

                    background: Rectangle {
                        gradient: Gradient {
                            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: (rowBtn.down ? "#56aff5" : rowBtn.hovered ? "#d9ebf9" : "#FFFFFF") }
                            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: (rowBtn.down ? "#1b93f1" : rowBtn.hovered ? "#a4b2bd" : "#F1F1F1") }
                            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: (rowBtn.down ? "#56aff5" : rowBtn.hovered ? "#d9ebf9" : "#FFFFFF") }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Loader {
                    sourceComponent: root.delegate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `model.itemId` or `modelData.itemId`? If that doesn't work you can define a property inside the loader and bind it to the model: `property var itemModel: model` (be sure to avoid name-clashes), that property will be made available inside the loaded component by the `Loader`

Comment: Yes I tried that and it didn't work, the property is actually still in the code above... `property alias model: listView.model`

Comment: but `listView.model` is different from the `model` property that is injected into a delegate by the ListView. You should define a new property inside the Loader as per [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#using-a-loader-within-a-view-delegate) (last paragraph)

Comment: @Amfasis that worked! Note I tried calling the property "data" and that wasn't working (I'm assuming that name is reserved/being used). Using the name modelData it worked. Thanks!

Comment: yes, `data` is a property on QQuickItem (not shown in designer)

Answer (score 0):

Capturing @Amfasis excellent comments to the question and adding some more detail....

Change your Loader reference to this:

```
                Loader {
                    sourceComponent: root.delegate
                    property int itemId: model.itemId
                    property string name: model.name
                }
```

fixes it. Here's why....

A Component declaration is put into the QML namespace hierarchy *where it is declared* not where it is instantiated at runtime. In other words, by declaring the delegate within main.qml, it can only see that namespace regardless of where it is instantiated at (in this case in AppDataListView).

More info here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#creation-context

As @Amfasis pointed out, the workaround in this case is to declare properties on the Loader to pass in the model references you need. In this case the Loader acts as a bridge of sorts from the ListView namespace over to the delegate Component's namespace in main.qml.

More info on that here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#using-a-loader-within-a-view-delegate

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in the documentation also... However, @Amfasis solution was more applicable for my specific needs as I did not need to specify the properties of the model being loaded within the custom ListView.. This way I can add a wide range of data without limitations.